# Upgrading Facebook Ads token to "Basic"

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ads-api

I am developing an app using the Facebook Ads api. Initially it is just a Python script which downloads ads performance information from my client and stores it in a database, where it is combined with information from other sources in order to provide better reporting for them.

It is not a web app (yet). It is just a Python script, working for a single business user account (yet!).

The developer token clearly isn't enough because it limits access to 5 Ads Accounts. I would like to upgrade to basic account however the approval form requires things such as providing a video demo, website of the app, privacy policy, etc. The app doesn't have those because it is not intended for general use (yet!!).

It seems that only an app focused on other Facebook users can apply to a Basic access token.

Is this so?

How can I upgrade my access token if my app is just a Python script running on a server?

Thank you! :-)

Comment: just for clarification, you don't upgrade an access token, you upgrade the app to a higher tier.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Facebook's review process and not a programming question

Comment: Hey Paul, you are right. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Igy, don't be mean, somebody may have the same doubts that I had when doing a programming job which is integrating to Facebook API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I just ended up filling the form and when asked for instructions of how to run the demo I explained that the app wasn't "demonstrable".

And the app tier was upgraded automatically.

Comment: How were you able to move forward without filling in the privacy policy url? I am doing the same thing but in R and not sure how to move forward to upgrade.

Comment: Did you try setting any url? You could for example create a blog on blogspot and set that url. I've just set the main home-page for the company I was creating the app for